# Android Studio - MainActivity.kt doesn't recognise any element by ID

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, button

I'm struggling with very common problem, I think. 
I've created a button in xml file and tagged it with ID. Then I wanted to make onClickListener in MainActivity.kt. But when I'm typing button's ID, it's marked red and it seems like Android Studio doesn't recognise it. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding project, but the problem still exist. Invalidate Caches/Restart didn't help as well. 
There are screens from Android Studio. 
[View from XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJFBL.png)

[View from MainActivity.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcMiX.png)

 
Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's best to include code directly in your question as text instead of as images.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use synthetic view bindings by Jetbrains, you need to make sure to add kotlin-android-extensions plug-in your module gradle file.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions' }
```

Stefan's answer above correcty states its considered obsolete now, but you can still use it. Or, again as in his answer, use findViewById.

Alternatively, you can use view bindings. For this, make sure to have this entry inside your Android section in your gradle file:

```
buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
    }
```

Refer to https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding for how to use it.

Comment: Oh the first method worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is using *synthetic* view bindings in Android Studio. As far as I found online, [they are not recommended anymore](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/882241). Use `findViewById` instead:

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.SUB_button)
button.setOnClickListener { ... }
```

Comment: My code looks like this now: 

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.SUB_button)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            SUB_Button.setText("Działa!")
        }

But ID's are still red 
(Sorry, I can't code this comment properly)

Comment: You're finding the view with ID ``SUB_button``, and assigning that to a variable called ``button``. So you need to do all your method calls (like ``setText``) on ``button``

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this in the import section

```
import android.widget.Button
```

And later in the class while referencing to the Button id you need to do this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
val SUB_Button = findById<Button>(R.id.SUB_Button)
<Rest code goes here>
```

After this your unresolved reference error will be gone.

N.B:  If the code shows error try to put this line`val SUB_Button = findById<Button>(R.id.SUB_Button)` in side the class MainActivity

Hope this helps :):)